# How to make scope in Symfony Oauth 2.0?

Tags: symfony, scope, oauth-2.0

I developed oauth 2.0 login with example that with http://blog.tankist.de/. But I cannot decide about scope. Can you help me?

Comment: The scopes are defined by the resource server. You should check the documentation of your resource server to know which scopes are available.

Comment: The OP is implementing an OAuth server. Check the link he posted. blog.tankist.de describes about setting up FOSOAuthServerBundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well documented here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/dealing_with_scopes.md

To configure allowed scopes in your application, you have to edit your app/config/config.yml file:

```
fos_oauth_server:
    service:
        options:
            supported_scopes: scope1 scope2
```

> The default behavior of the FOSOAuthServerBundle is to use scopes as roles. In the previous example, it would allow us to use the roles ROLE_SCOPE1, and ROLE_SCOPE2 (scopes are automatically uppercased).

You can check like this in your controller

```
// symfony 2.6
$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_SCOPE1')

// symfony < 2.6
$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SCOPE1')
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why this was downvoted? The OP is implementing an OAuth server. Check the link he posted. http://blog.tankist.de/ describes about setting up FOSOAuthServerBundle.

Comment: I saw these. But i don't undestand well and $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_SCOPE1') not working. How to write security.yml

Comment: You have requested a non-existent service "security.authorization_checker". Did you mean this: "security.authentication.manager"?

Comment: What is the symfony version you are using?

Comment: 2.5 is my symfony version

Comment: The service `security.authorization_checker` was introduced in 2.6. You should then be using `$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SCOPE1')`

Comment: $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SCOPE1') is checked user role? I wanna check access token's role. Or these same? How to i set role?

Comment: Read the documentation carefully. OAuth server bundle assigns the ROLES depending upon the scope of the access token. If the access token has scope `scope1`, when authenticated using the access token, it assigns the role `ROLE_SCOPE1`. It is like, a user has authenticated using the access token and has the roles same as the access token